# Align Image and Label to middle center?

Tags: align

how to align the paragraph or text to top and bottom in the right side of the image. Even I Changed the font size.

```
       \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} %package to manage images
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\title{image ang label}
\author{jasond.worked }
\date{September 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\parbox{10mm}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}
\LARGE There's a picture of a galaxy above


\end{document}
```

My Result:
[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

Comment: If you want to use a `\parbox` as you are, then put the `\LARGE` before it (or leave it out if you don't want it) and use `\parbox[m]{10}...`. Since you're loading the adjustbox package with the export option, you could forgo the parbox, and use its valign option with the image: `\includegraphics[width=10mm,valign=c]{example-image} There's ...`.

Comment: I try the LARGE first but space at the bottom is higher than the TOP

Comment: It might look that way because there are no descenders in the word "There" which starts your sentence. Put the word "galaxy" which has two descenders right after the image and see then if it looks like there's more space at the bottom compared to the top. If you don't want descenders taken in to account, that's more work and you may need to manually adjust with `\raisebox`, unless someone else has a better idea.